# Dialog box doesn't click on onClick event

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following code I am using as a tutorial:

`CommentSend.js`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";

const CommentSend = () => {
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

  return (                                 
              <form>                                    
                  <Button            
                    onClick={() => setOpen(true)}        
                    type="submit"    
                  >
                      Add Comment
                  </Button>
                  <Dialog
                    open={open}
                  >
                    <FormControl fullWidth>
                      <InputLabel htmlFor="comment">Comment</InputLabel>
                      <Input
                        id="comment"
                        onChange={event => setDescription(event.target.value)}
                      />                      
                    </FormControl>
                  </Dialog>
              </form>
          );}

export default CommentSend;
```

After clicking the button, the dialog box doesn't open up instead page refreshes. I am not sure what is going on here.

Comment: your button is of type `submit` this means that the form will submit when you click it. a form submit, submits the webpage (aka page refresh). Instead specify a different type for the button (like `<button type="button"`). You should probably put a `onSubmit` on your form element too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page is refreshing as the button's type is "submit" which triggers the page to refresh.

*You can follow along by forking Sandbox.*
[image: Edit so.answer.56695455]

So you can stop the issue in two different ways.

### 1 Remove "type=submit"

```js
const CommentSend = () => {
  // ... redacted for brevity    
  return (
    <form>
      <Button
        onClick={e => {
          setOpen(true);
        }}
      >
        Add Comment
      </Button>
      <Dialog open={open}>
         // ... redacted for brevity
      </Dialog>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Check out the working demo below.
[image: demo]

### 2 Prevent default on button click event.

```js
 <Button
    onClick={e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      setOpen(true);
    }}
    type="submit"
  >
```

Should you need to keep the `type="submit"` for the button, you can prevent the refresh using the event passed to "onClick" callback and call `.preventDefault()`.

[image]

Comment: great answer and explanation! you could also change the button type to be something other than submit if its purpose is not to submit. but thats just a small nit-picky point haha :D +1

Comment: Great catch @JohnRuddell Being explicit with `type="button"` would be a better idea then dropping or leaving "type='submit'" for accessibility reasons - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role